# How to get all the facts used to get an query solution in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, fact

I'm trying to print all the facts used to get an query solution, and I hope to print nothing if the unification is failed. So I write this:

```
a:-
    b,c,writeln(b^c->a).
b:-
    d,writeln(d->b).
c:-
    fail,writeln(e->c).
d:-
    writeln(d).
a:-
    b,d,writeln(b^d->a).
```

However, when I query `a.`, I got the following output sadly:

```
d
d->b
d
d->b
d
b^d->a
true.
```

Someone seems to tell me that Prolog has a built-in machanism to show all the facts used to do a query. Is he true? How can I get right output?

Answer (score 1):

Your program has no variables, and thus no unification.

**edit**: Or better, in *abstract* sense, Prolog *select* between a list of Horn clauses unifying the *current goal* with each rule head. But actual Prologs replace the selection phase with indexing, for performance, and attempt unification on arguments.

When you invoke `a`, that invokes `b` **and** `c`, **and** *print* an expression.

The built in mechanism to show all the *rules* used in a query is probably [trace](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=trace/0). See your Prolog manual for details, it's a fairly complex argument, involving inner workings of the system, and the 'architecture' of the language you are targeting.

There is of course no *right* output, apart what you can see. That's the semantic you wrote.